# Install Jenkins as a Service or Run it behind Apatche

Tags: jenkins

I understand that there are two ways of installing Jenkins:

1) Running Jenkins behind Apache (Using the War file)

2) Installing Jenkins as a Windows Service(using the windows Installer)

I am in the process of creating a CI, Auto-Deployment and Scheduled Automation runs for my project. So in this case which kind of installation should be better. I just do not want to choose the wrong one and end up recreating jobs to the other kind.

I have few questions:

1) If I choose to install as a Windows service( using the windows installer), do I still have to install an web server like IIS or Apatche for accessing my Jenkins URL, or does Jenkins have something inbuilt in it and I do not have to add an web server for accessing Jenkins?

2)If Jenkins as a Windows Service(using the windows Installer) needs IIS, I have  steps in my project in which I have  to restart IIS manually to generate NCover reports. In such cases, would Jenkins also be down?

3) Jenkins website states the following: "In situations where you have existing web sites on your server, you may find it useful to run Jenkins (or the servlet container that Jenkins runs in) behind Apache, so that you can bind Jenkins to the part of a bigger website that you may have.". 
I would be hosting our application locally using IIS, in that case, should I chose to use the WAR installer instead of the windows installer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not run Jenkin's on Windows but I believe its the same as other platforms...

1. No if you install Jenkins with the installer you will not need IIS or Apache
2. See the answer to 1, If you don't use IIS to run Jenkins restarting it won't bring down Jenkins
3. It sounds like you want to run your existing site under IIS and leave Jenkins running on its own.  I think the windows installer for Jenkins will do exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

I have run Jenkins on Windows and Unix environment.

Just wanted to add more to Ben's answer:

Windows if you install as windows service you will not need anything and for this following wiki should be more than enough:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service

To add more to 3rd point:
Normally web sites are hosted behind Apache httpd server. If you are using one then you can configure both IIS web server and Jenkins accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In my previous company, we was running Jenkins as a service (with the solution proposed by Vinay above).

It worked well and you don't have to install an application server like Apache.

The only thing you have to take care is the user which launch the Windows service.

If your Jenkins server needs to access some ressource on the network, maybe you have to use a LDAP user to launch your service instead of using the "local system account".